# cl-block Vs let form in elisp

Tags: elisp

when to use `cl-block` over the most common `let` scoping?

When a form is expected to return multiple possible values, is `cl-block` the choice over `let?`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what gave you the impression that `cl-block` and `let` did similar things?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that it's best to avoid `cl-block`. There are only 23 uses
of `cl-block` in the whole Emacs core.  I've been writing Emacs
packages for some time and I couldn't tell at the spot what `cl-block`
does. A list of values is usually better, or eieio if you want complex
things.

Answer (score 3):

`cl-block` isn't designed for the same purpose as `let`. Its purpose is to be used in macros to work with control flow in the way which resembles Common Lisp. One would use `cl-block` to implement functionality of `return-from` or a pattern-matching device with guards etc. It's not expected that non-library code would use this macro.